# Can i use gzip compression in POST file upload with PHP?

Tags: php, upload, gzip

Can i use gzip compression in POST file upload with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably only by using javascript to compress and upload via XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

The "SWFUpload Resize" branch of swfupload contains an API for zlib compression:

[http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/source/browse/swfupload/#swfupload%2Fbranches%2FSWFUpload%20Resize](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/source/browse/swfupload/#swfupload/branches/SWFUpload%20Resize)